# Move PS4 HDD to PS4 Pro? Keep data intact?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, hardware, playstation-plus, hard-drive

I upgraded my PS4 to a 2 TB HDD,  can I just install it into a new PS4 Pro? Im asking because Im worried there might be problems with the software and/or firmware differences between the playstations. Or with the games and what not already on the HDD. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to move the hard drive to the new console without formatting it. When the new PS4 Pro detects the hard drive, you'll be asked to format it, which means all your data will be deleted.

You will need to transfer the data from the PS4 to the PS4 Pro using the PS4's Data Transfer functionality, but that means you won't be able to move the 2 TB drive to the PS4 Pro.

In order to use the 2TB drive on the PS4 Pro, you'll need a third hard drive. The process is as follows:

1. Backup original PS4 (2 TB) drive to external USB drive (may need to be 2 TB depending on how much data you have). You can use the PS4 to create a backup.
2. Move the 2 TB drive to PS4 Pro and format the drive when requested.
3. Connect the USB hard drive with backup and restore the data to the PS4 Pro.
4. Connect the 1 TB drive from the PS4 Pro into the old PS4 and sell / keep.

Comment: Actually, he doesn't need to backup and restore. PS4 has a "Transfer data from another PS4" option. Connect both PS4s to a TV and networked together. Do any necessary HDD upgrade to the PS4 Pro, then boot up the PS4 Pro and when you go through the initialization steps, select the Transfer from Another PS4 option (also available in the PS4 Settings menu).

Comment: I've already mentioned the data transfer step. However, if the end goal is to use the 2TB hard drive in the new console, they would need to do the backup / restore the hard way.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I misread what you were trying to say.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to rephrase my answer if it helps.